# What's the deal with np.memmap

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I recently found [this post on the pytorch messageboard](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/quickly-loading-raw-binary-files/797) which suggested using [np.memmap](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) to load in large .bin files. I am more accustomed to using [np.fromfile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) to do this sort of thing (in fact the documentation says it's a "highly efficient way of reading binary data with a known data-type").
So I tried a time comparison between the two functions:

```
def read1(fname_bin):
    return np.memmap(filename, dtype=np.float32, mode='r+').__array__()
```

versus

```
def read2(fname_bin):
    return np.fromfile(fname, dtype=np.float32)
```

I then tried loading in 1,000 arrays with around 400,000 elements - the time comparison is below:
| method | mean (ms) | median (ms) | std (ms) |
| :------: | :----: | :------: | :---: |
| read1() | 0.6364 | 0.6204 | 0.0566 |
| read2() | 0.9435 |0.7607 |0.3729 |

Which is great, and the CPU usage is lower as well. But elsewhere I've read that maybe this operation is creating a separate file somewhere?
Maybe the problem is that I don't really understand the difference between a memory map and reading a file in from disk.
My main question is - can I safely use np.memmap to load in large .bin files as numpy arrays?

Comment: Roughly speaking, `read2` reads the whole file into memory, whereas `read1` sets up a "lazy load". `read1` is quicker in itself, but subsequent operations on the memory-mapped array may be slower because they need to load data from disk that hasn't yet been brought into memory.

Comment: Is that true even when using the .__array__() method?

Comment: Yes, `__array__()` just returns what's in effect an ndarray view on the memory-mapped array. For a quick test, put the `__array__()` call on a separate line from creating the `memmap` object, and check memory usage before and after.

Comment: oh nice thank you! If you put this response in an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly speaking, `read2` reads the whole file into memory, whereas `read1` (using the `memmap`) sets up a "lazy load": so this is not quite a like-for-like comparison.

`read1` is quicker in itself, but subsequent operations on the memory-mapped array may be slower because they need to load data from disk that hasn't yet been brought into memory.

`__array__()` doesn't materialise the whole array in memory: it returns an `ndarray` object but essentially this is a view on the memory-mapped object.

For a quick demonstration, you can do something like this (I did this on Google Colab):

```
import numpy as np
import psutil
process = psutil.Process()

print(process.memory_info().rss)
arr = np.ones(shape=(1_000, 1_000_000), dtype=int)
print(process.memory_info().rss)  # shows about 8 GB memory usage
arr.tofile('sample_data/memmap.npy')
```

[restart the kernel]

```
import numpy as np
import psutil
process = psutil.Process()

mmarr = np.memmap('sample_data/memmap.npy')
print(process.memory_info().rss) ## about 109 MB memory usage
x = mmarr.__array__()
print(process.memory_info().rss) ## about 109 MB memory usage
```

Whereas if `__array__()` loaded the whole array, we'd expect to have about 8GB used again by the end of the second snippet.